# Replace the "paragraph mark" with a "manual line break", In the headers only

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a word document. I would like to replace the "paragraph mark" with a "manual line break", In the headers only, with keeping the header number.

I tried using the normal search/replace, but it removes the header number, so I lose that information. I don't want that to happen, is there any way to work around this?

example:

```
1.2.1.1 Introduction ¶
```

after search/replace looks like this:

```
Introduction ↵
```

However, I want it to look like this:

```
1.2.1.1 Introduction ↵
```

Is there a VBA that can do that? or is this impossible?

Answer (score 1):

You can consider the "paragraph mark" as containing all the info about the style of the paragraph. The replacement you do removes that info: the header becomes a mere part of what was the following paragraph. There's no more header, no more header number. VBA cannot solve that.

To keep the header numbering working, you must preserve the headers styles. If it is the look that you want to change, change the style format definition. To do that, select one header paragraph and give it the look you want then right click on the header style in the ribbon and choose "Update Headerxx to match selection".